# EF saving with F# and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, f#

Based on the great samples from [Daniel Mohl and his book](https://github.com/dmohl/fs-web-cloud-mobile).

I have and ASP.NET MVC application in F# with the online template for it. So far I have my model, entities, controller, repository, view... all very generalized and reusable, and the querying is great. But I can't find a way to keep the saving to the DbContext part equally reusable.

For the querying part the code for Repository.fs is as follows

```ml
namespace Melopienso.Repositories

open System
open System.Linq

module Repository =
    let get (source:IQueryable<_>) queryFn =
        queryFn source |> Seq.toList

    let getAll () =
        fun s -> query { for x in s do
                         select x }

    let find filterPredFn =
        filterPredFn
        |> fun fn s -> query { for x in s do
                               where (fn()) }

    let getTop rowCount =
        rowCount
        |> fun cnt s -> query { for x in s do
                                take cnt }
```

........... (More Code) ...........

And in the controller I pass everything necessary:

```ml
namespace Melopienso.Controllers

open System
open System.Web.Mvc
open Melopienso.Models
open Melopienso.Repositories
open Repository
open Utils

[<HandleError>]
type CategoriesController(context:IDisposable, ?repository) =
    inherit Controller()

let fromRepository =
    match repository with
    | Some v -> v
    | _ -> (context :?> MelopiensoEntities).Categories
    |> Repository.get

new() = new CategoriesController(new MelopiensoEntities())

member this.Index () =
    getAll() |> fromRepository |> this.View

override x.Dispose disposing =
    context.Dispose()
    base.Dispose disposing

[<HttpGet>]
member this.Create () =
    this.View()
```

........... (More Code) ...........

Now, when saving the problem resides in how to make it as reusable as that. If I pass the DbSet I need a way to call the context, which I don't know how to find it from the specific DbSet (doubt it is even possible).

If I pass both the DbContext and DbSet, I can't do something like

```ml
use nameOfDbContext
    nameOfDbContext.NameOfDbSet.Add entity
```

The only option I find to hardcode anything, but that just doesn't seem right.

It's a shame but Daniel's great examples don't do the saving part in a "traditional" EF way and use buses, etc, which is great but I first would like to have a basic application fully working, and then improve from there with Async controllers, mailboxes, etc.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you pass both the `DbContext` and the `DbSet`, and use the `DbContext` for saving, and access the `DbSet` directly (don't try and go through `DbContext`) for queries etc.?

You can also get a `DbSet` from a `DbContext` if you have the type, which might also help:

```
myDbContext.Set<'a>()
```

Comment: Hello Danny! It's been a long time since I posted his and I finally took a totally different route, but I'll try to check it out as it for sure will be valuable for other projects. Thanks a lot!